# Can you make a section of HTML only affected by one stylesheet?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a stylesheet linked to every page of a website, and another one that overrides the first. What I want to do is add content using jQuery (contained within one div tag) after the page had loaded, but I only want it to be affected by the first stylesheet, while the rest is affected by both. The second stylesheet is dynamic by the way, it may or may not affect the content I add, but I want to make sure it doesn't.

Is there some way I can achieve this using either HTML5, or JavaScript/jQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to fix CSS properties that overrides others but you can use wrapper div like you said for that section of page and write CSS in first CSS document just for that section e.g.

```
<div id="wrapper">


   ...


</div>


#wrapper a {
  ...
}
#wrapper b {
  ...
}
#wrapper p {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this because it means a _lot_ of extra CSS, doesn't seem like I have much choice though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just make more CSS rules to fit a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

Make your stylesheet affect only the desired section by using an identifier for the container

```
<div class="my_section">

  <!-- your loaded content -->

</div>
```

css

```
.my_section label{}
.my_section input{}
/* etc */
```

but if you find that some elements are still being affected by other css rules (or if you simply want to make sure) then use the `!important` decalaration

```
.my_section label{ width : 100px !important; }
.my_section input{ border: 1px solid lightgray !important; }
```

Furthermore, if you find that some elements are still affected even when you used the !important technique than add the css property to the style attribute

```
<label style="width : 100px !important;">...</label>
```

This way you'll hopefully prevent your newly loaded elements from being affected by other css rules.